# Using MongoDB in Twisted. Why shouldn't I use pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've read that I should not be using pymongo in twisted project because pymongo isn't asynchronous. I'm having problem with understanding this whole idea... As far as I understand I should put my code to Deferred to avoid blocking my application. Am I right? So all database operations should be in Deferred method? Take a look at this:

```
class Tracker(protocol.Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):

        self.db = factory.db

    def dataReceived(self, data):

        deferred = threads.deferToThread(self.handle, data)
        deferred.addCallback(self.on_success)
        deferred.addErrback(self.on_error)

    def on_success(self, _None, response):

        self.transport.write(response)

    def on_error(self, failure):

        logging.error('Error in deferred: %s' % failure.getErrorMessage())

    def handle(self, tracker, input):

        self.db.buffer.insert({ }) # writing data to database
        return 'success'


class Server(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient()
        self.db = self.client.my_database

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Client(self)

reactor.listenTCP(6969, Server())
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in thinking that pymongo is not asynchronous. You should spend some time and learn the difference between asynchronous (event-loop) systems and threaded systems. They are fundamentally different approaches to programming systems.

In your method you have used the deferToThread method, which will defer until the thread releases and returns a value, and it will happen asynchronously due to the magic of twisted.internet.threads.

However, this is in poor spirit of twisted. Twisted provides access to network programming protocols from the ground up - raw, all the way through encryption layers. So using the pymongo module like this is just circumventing the purpose of twisted entirely. In a pinch, sure you could use this as a stop-gap solution, but you don't get any of the benefit of the robust twisted framework, the scalability of event-driven systems and your database access will still behave in a threaded capacity - even if twisted is running asynchronously.

Have a look at something like txmongo to see the twisted way of doing it:
https://github.com/twisted/txmongo

Also: your code looks like it doesn't provide the correct number of parameters to the handle() method, you provide data (1 argument) but it is expecting 2 arguments.

Also again: following PEP8 you may want to consider consistent code over pythonic code, the naming scheme in twisted is camel case, as well as the callback methods are not prefixed with 'on', they are either prefixed with cb, eb or none.